# Java deserialization: final variable value is not assigned

Tags: java, serialization

I'm exploring Java Serialization and Deserialization but wonder how Deserialization works.

Here is my Serialization and Deserialization Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
public class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Serial obj = new Serial();
        Serial ObjNew = null;
        try{
           FileOutputStream fob= new FileOutputStream("file.src"); 
           ObjectOutputStream oob= new ObjectOutputStream(fob);
           oob.writeObject(obj);
           oob.close();
        }catch(Exception fnf){
            fnf.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.src");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            ObjNew=(Serial)ois.readObject();
        }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException fnf){
            fnf.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        System.out.println("OLD: "+obj);
        System.out.println("NEW: "+ObjNew);

    }
}
```

Here Serializable Class Code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Serial implements Serializable {
    private final String ok="DONE";
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ok;
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine with above code.
But When I try to Deserialize the Object with this code.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
public class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Serial ObjNew = null;
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("file.src");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            ObjNew=(Serial)ois.readObject();
        }
        catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException fnf){
            fnf.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
        System.out.println("NEW: "+ObjNew);

    }
}
```

and I just changed the value of `String ok="Do";` in Serializable Class Just to test Deserialize output.

But it just printing `Do` instead of the value `DONE` that stored in file. 
Why it is printing just `Do`? 
**why it not reading the value from file?**
Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `final` variable can only be assigned once.

Remove the final modifier, and try again.

Comment: Nice Thanks Solved the Problem.

Comment: and that's because... the line ``private final String ok="DONE";`` adds a field "ok" of type ``String`` with modifiers ``private`` and ``final`` to the enclosing class and puts an assignment like ``ok = "DONE";`` into the [instance initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). Not to says that constants always *may* be substituted by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

A requirement of a Java class that is serializable is that it has access to a no-argument constructor in its first non-serializable superclass. Java serialization utilizes this no-arg constructor.  This is not exactly the same thing as stating that it creates a new class by this constructor, but certain aspects of the class's construction are carried out before the fields are set within the class.  One of these aspects is the setting of final constants, as they need to be set before the class can be considered "constructed".

You have a final field.  It cannot be set after class construction.  With such an item, the field is not serialized into the file on disk (at least I don't think it is) and even if it was and was read from disk it could not reset the field because then the field wouldn't honor the "final" keyword.  If you change it to non-final, you should expect different results.

Since you are effectively borrowing one class definition and populating it with a snapshot of what that definition was, you need a facility to identify when the definitions have drifted too far apart to be reconcilable.  This is the primary purpose of the `serialVersionID` member.

Comment: "*Java serialization utilizes the no-arg constructor.*" not quite, in that case we wouldn't be able to deserialize object without no-argument constructors. From what I remember it uses mechanism which doesn't involve constructor (`Unsafe...Something` class).

Comment: A requirement of a Java class that is serializable is that it has access to a no-argument constructor in its first non-serializable superclass.  We might quibble about the meaning of "utilize" but if you can create a serilizable class that doesn't utilize a no-args constructor, I'd like to see it.  Note that I didn't say it needed a constructor to deserialize nor that it was constructed by running the "init" method with no args....

Comment: You are right. But could you add this explanation to your answer to avoid confusion?

Comment: Updated (quickly).  If you find the quick edit unpleasing, feel free to suggest and edit.

Comment: It looks fine. Thanks for improvement of your post and for teaching me something new :)

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on your `final` field modifier.

I have red the source code of `ObjectInputStream` and found this code

```
    Object obj;
    try {
        obj = desc.isInstantiable() ? desc.newInstance() : null; // here instance created
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw (IOException) new InvalidClassException(
            desc.forClass().getName(),
            "unable to create instance").initCause(ex);
    }
```

Once your instance created the value **"DO"** applied to the field, and since field is `final` it cannot be modified anymore